# Transfer (NOT COPY) files to remote computer?

Tags: ssh, terminal, file-transfer

I know that using scp over SSH will copy the files between hosts, but what if I don't want to copy them but instead **move** them over entirely?

What command could I use using a secure connection over SSH or otherwise?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? http://serverfault.com/questions/363922/hov-to-move-files-with-scp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "move".

On a single filesystem, you can "move" a file by renaming it; the file itself stays in place, but a new name gets added and an old one removed (this is not guaranteed to be atomic, either - if both "a" and "b" exists, then calling `mv a b` may very briefly have both names refer to the same file "a", before that old name goes away).

To move a file from one place to another in the general case, you need to create a file with the new name, copy the data into it, and then delete the old one. On a local machine, but different filesystems, the "mv" command does that for you behind the scenes - you can see this happen this by running `strace mv a /other/filesystem/b`.

To do this between computers without a shared network filesystem, you have to do it step by step yourself, e.g. `scp a otherhost:/path/to/new/a && rm a` (the ampersands mean that the local file is only deleted if scp succeeded, which means it's extremely likely that the remote copy was made successfully).